# Bash - if and for statements

Tags: bash

I am little unfamiliar with the 'if...then...fi' and the 'for' statements syntax.

Could anyone explain what the "$2/$fn" and  "/etc/*release" in the code snippets below mean?...specifically on the use of the forward slash....and the asterisk...

```
if [ -f "$filename" ]; then
    if [ ! -f "$2/$fn" ]; then
        echo "$fn is missing from $2"
        missing=$((missing + 1))
    fi
fi
```

and

```
function system_info
{


if ls /etc/*release 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "<h2>System release info</h2>"
    echo "<pre>"
    for i in /etc/*release; do

        # Since we can't be sure of the
        # length of the file, only
        # display the first line.

        head -n 1 $i
    done
    uname -orp
    echo "</pre>"
fi

}   # end of system_info
```

...thx for the help...

Comment: Using `ls` to test file existence is ugly and brittle.  The proper way to code it is, unfortunately, somewhat dependent on your shell.  This particular set of nested loops could probably be condensed to a single loop, which simply doesn't execute if there are no matches on the glob (i.e. if `/etc/*release` doesn't match any files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/etc/*release` : here the `*` will match any number of any characters, so any thing `/etc/0release` , `/etc/asdfasdfr_release` etc will be matched. Simply stated, it defined all the files in the `/etc/` directory which ends with the string `release`.

The `$2` is the 2nd commandline argument to the shell script, and `$fn` is some other shell variable. The `"$2/$fn"` after the variable substitutions will make a string, and the `[ -f "$2/$fn" ]` will test if the string formed after the substitution forms a path to a regular file which is specified by the `-f` switch. If it is a regular file then the body of `if` is executed.

In the `for` loop the loop will loop for all the files ending with the string `release` in the directory `/etc` (the path). At each iteration `i` will contain the next such file name, and for each iteration the first 1 line of the file is displayed with the `head` command by getting the file name from variable `i` within the body.

It is better to check the manual `man bash`  and for if condition check `man test` . Here is a good resource: http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/

Answer (score 0):

The forward slash is the path separator, and the `*` is a file glob character.  `$2/$fn` is a path where `$2` specifies the directory and `$fn` is the filename.  `/etc/*release` expands to the space separated list of all the files in `/etc` whose name ends in "release"

Answer (score 0):

Dollar sign marks variable. The "-f" operator means "file exsists".

So,

```
[ -f "$filename" ]
```

checks if there is file named the same as value contained in $filename variable.

Simmilar, if we assume that $2 = "some_folder", and $fn = "some_file", expression

```
[ ! -f "$2/$fn" ]
```

returns true if file some_folder/some_file doesn't exsist.

Now, about asterisk - it marks "zero or more of any character(s)". So, expression:

```
for i in /etc/*release; do
```

will iterate trough all folders named by that pattern, for example:
/etc/release, /etc/666release, /etc/wtf_release...

I hope this helps.

Comment: `-f` switch with the `test` or `[` command means if the file path is a regular file.